# Inverse Laplace Transform of an exponential containing an exponential

Tags: exponential-function, inverse, laplace-transform

I am trying to calculate the Inverse Laplace Transform of $$F(\lambda)=\exp\left[\mu(e^{-\lambda}-1)\right],$$ where $\mu$ is just a constant, to obtain $f(Q)$. My attempt so far brought me to a fairly recognizable integral (since $F(s)$ does not have any singularities)
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{Q\lambda}\exp\left[\mu(e^{-\lambda}-1)\right]d\lambda$$

By setting $e^{-\lambda}=s$ I obtained after some manipulations

$$\int_0^\infty s^{Q+1}e^{\mu s}ds.$$

From here on is the part where I am stuck. I know I could do another change of variables to arrive at an expression containing the Gamma-function or I could use Feynman's Integration trick to derive under the integral but I don't see how either of those options would give me a decent anwers. My supervisor hinted me that I should find that $f(Q)=e^{-\mu}\mu^Q/Q!$, a Poisson distribution.

Comment: The moment generating function is a summation for discrete distributions and for the Poisson distribution is
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{t k} \frac{\mu^k e^{-\mu}}{k!}=e^{\mu(e^t-1)}$ which is your function with $t=-\lambda$.

Comment: The inverse transform does not exist as an ordinary function ($F$ is periodic on a vertical line). We have
$$\mathcal L^{-1}[F](Q) =
e^{-\mu} \mathcal L^{-1} {\left[ \lambda \mapsto
 \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac {\mu^k} {k!} e^{-k \lambda} \right]}(Q) =
\frac {e^{-\mu} \mu^Q} {Q!} \sum_{k \geq 0} \delta(Q - k),$$
which is a pdf of a discrete distribution.